# How to create SOAP service using ZF2?

Tags: php, web-services, soap, wsdl, zend-framework2

What is wrong in my code? How to create SOAP service for my Math class?
Please note that, i don't mentioned namespace for Math.php because if i did that i got `class Math does not exist` message on browser.
Without mentioning namespace of Math class how to create Math object in indexAction().
Please guid me how to create my first wsdl for Math class.

**Folder structure**
Module
--Soap
----Controller
------>IndexController.php
----Services
------>Math.php

**IndexController.php**

```
include_once __DIR__ . '/../Services/Math.php'
class IndexController extends AbstractActionController
{
  private $_URI = "http://zf2.services/soap";
  public function indexAction()
  {
   $server = new Server(null, array('uri' => $this->_URI));
   $server->setClass('Math');
   //$server->setObject(new Math());
   $server->handle();
  }
}
```

**Math.php**

```
//namespace Soap\Services;
    class Math
    {
       /**
        * Method
        * @return string
        */
       public function greeting()
       {
         return 'Hello world';
       }
    }
```

**Resulted XML**

```
<SOAP-ENV ..>
 <SOAP-ENV:Body>
  <SOAP-ENV:Fault>
   <faultcode>sender</faultcode>
   <faultstring>Invalid XML</faultstring>
  </SOAP-ENV:Fault>
 </SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are right about the namespace written in the `Math.php`.

Try this in IndexController.php -

```
include_once __DIR__ . '/../Services/Math.php';

class IndexController extends AbstractActionController {

    private $_URI = "http://zf2.services/soap";

    public function indexAction() {
        $autodiscover = new \Zend\Soap\AutoDiscover();
        $autodiscover->setClass('Math')
                     ->setBindingStyle(array('style' => 'document'))
                     ->setUri($this->_URI);
        header('Content-type: application/xml');
        echo $autodiscover->toXml();
        exit();
    }
}
```

I have tried it and it works fine.

Comment: what is wrong in my previous approach? and how can i consume this wsdl from soapclient?

Comment: can you provide some reference links which talk about ZF2 SOAP?

Comment: This link is enough - http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.3/en/modules/zend.soap.auto-discovery.html 
For detail implementation, you will have to google blogs written specially for it. At least that's how I learnt ZF2. Good luck.