# Zend_Soap_Server/Client doesn't work. Returns "looks like we got no XML document"

Tags: php, soap, zend-framework

I am working with Zend Framework, and I need to make a web service using Zend_Soap. After searching for 3 days, I've decided to ask myself. After creating Zend_Soap_Server i get message 
    `<SOAP-ENV ..>
     <SOAP-ENV:Body>
      <SOAP-ENV:Fault>
       <faultcode>sender</faultcode>
       <faultstring>Invalid XML</faultstring>
      </SOAP-ENV:Fault>
     </SOAP-ENV:Body>
    </SOAP-ENV>`
Then I tried [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24954999/how-to-create-soap-service-using-zf2), and I got XML to work by using Zend_Soap_AutoDiscover, but when I try to connect Zend_Soap_Client...

```
<?php

require_once 'Zend/Loader.php';
Zend_Loader::loadClass('Zend_Soap_Client');

$options  = array(
    'location' => 'http://zend/service/soap',
    'uri' => 'http://zend/service/soap'
);
try {
    $client = new Zend_Soap_Client(null, $options);
    $foo = $client->foo();
    var_dump($foo);
} catch (Exception $e) {
    die($e->getMessage());
}
```

the response I get is

> looks like we got no XML document

The code on server ($soap is not used because I couldn't get it to work):

```
public function soapAction() {
    $this->_helper->layout()->disableLayout();
    $this->getHelper('viewRenderer')->setNoRender(true);
    $soap   =   new Zend_Soap_Server(null,array(
        'uri' => 'http://zend/service/soap'
    ));
    $soap->setClass('API_SoapFunctions');
    $soap->setUri('http://zend/service/soap');
    $autodiscover = new Zend_Soap_AutoDiscover();
    $autodiscover->setClass('API_SoapFunctions')->setBindingStyle(array('style' => 'document'))->setUri('http://zend/service/soap');
    header('Content-type: application/xml');
    echo $autodiscover->toXml();
    //$soap->handle();
}
```

Comment: I just got to ask... you're not using the URI `http://zend/service/soap` when you're running your code, right?

Comment: I have a file service.php next to index.php in public folder

Comment: Sure, but in the above code you have `http://zend/service/soap` as the URL, not your `service.php`-file. Is the above code your actual code?

Comment: It is. ServiceController has soapAction() that creates the server, and the service.php file is creating the client that, I guess, should connect to server with server's location. (or am I doing something wrong?)

Comment: It looks like the client is trying to connect to `http://zend/service/soap` which isn't a valid URL, unless you have added `zend` in your host file and pointed it to your server... I might be missing something here, but I can't see that you add any other URL anywhere...

Answer (score 0):

Try this approach in your controller:

```
if(check if you have a request for WSDL){
    $server = new Zend_Soap_AutoDiscover('Zend_Soap_Wsdl_Strategy_ArrayOfTypeComplex');
}else{
    $server = new Zend_Soap_Server('URI_HERE'); 
}
$server->setClass('WS_CLASS_HERE');
$server->handle();
```